# Use separate properties file for dependency jar and main war

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration, dependency-properties

I have 2 Spring Boot apps. AppA is a jar that primarily acts as a service (services, external api calls, etc). AppB is a war that has AppA as a dependency.

AppA (jar) currently does not have a `MySvcApplication.java` file `@SpringBootApplication` because it is never ran on it's own and I noticed that when running AppB, that file is never ran. AppB (war) has a `MyMainApplication.java` file with `@SpringBootApplication` with `scanBasePackages` property.

I would like AppA and AppB to have their own properties files, and if possible, a shared properties file (inside the svc) (i.e. svc.properties, main-app.properties, common.properties).

I have read on a few ways (in-app, command-line) to change the file name (via spring.config.name) but that applies for the war (in `MyMainApplication.java`), but not the dependency jar.

```
SpringApplicationBuilder()
  .properties("spring.config.name=myproject")
  .sources(MyApplication.class)
  .run(args);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new property file in AppB (example svc.properties) for shared properties and include the same in application.properties of AppB
spring.profiles.include=svc
It should work.

Comment: You mentioned AppB both times. I would like to have svc.properties and common.properties in AppA (jar) and main-app.properties in AppB (war). Can you please show a more detailed example?